# C++ compilation error "does not name a type" with the type defined above where the error occurs?

Tags: c++

I wrote a package, and I confronted "does not name a type" problem while compilation.

Here's the code:
skeleton.h

```
  #include "gp.h"

  ...       

  class Formula : public GP
  {
     ...
  };

  ...

  class FormulaPopulation : public GPPopulation
  {
     ...
     Formula* NthMyGP (int n) { return (Formula*) GPContainer::Nth (n); }
     ...
  };
```

When I compiled, the compiler would indicate that Formula(in FormulaPopulation) does not name a type, but the class Formula is defined just above class FormulaPopulation, I have no idea why this error happens...

If you want more info, you can download the package [here](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~b98901160/printNatural.tar.gz).
(After downloading, untar this file and make under the directory "printNatural". you can see the error)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the actual snippet of code? Your post is missing semicolons after closing brackets of class definitions, that could easily confuse the compiler.

Comment: Sorry I made that mistake...it's not the problem of semicolons.

Comment: Your tarball doesn't build because files are missing, but `extern vector<myFNode> Formula;` might have something to do with your problem. Oh, and *don't* write `using namespace std;` in your headers, ever.

Comment: Post code that demonstrates the problem. Summarizing doesn't work.

Comment: Thx molbdnilo, I fixed the original problem by changing `extern vector<myFNode> Formula;` to `extern vector<myFNode> Formulas;` to avoid the "does not name a type" issue.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Can you post an answer so that I can close this question? Thx~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tarball doesn't build because files are missing, but there is a declaration of an
`extern vector<myFNode> Formula;` that would cause the conflict.

It's very confusing that it's apparently possible to define the `Formula` class without causing a conflict while it's impossible to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your copied and pasted code is the same as what is in your project, you are missing semicolons:

```
  #include "gp.h"
  class Formula : public GP
  {
     ...
  }; // <-- HERE

  ...

  class FormulaPopulation : public GPPopulation
  {
     ...
     Formula* NthMyGP (int n) { return (Formula*) GPContainer::Nth (n); }
     ...
  }; // <-- HERE
```

Comment: Sorry for making that mistake...it's not the problem of semicolons.